# I want to have access inside the body not to the \arg[n] list but with \A[n] if I call \MAT{A, 1, 2, 3, 4}?

Tags: input, token-lists, variable

I would like to set matrices using the code:

```
\newcommand{\MAT}[1]{
\setsepchar{,}
\readlist\arg{#1}
\arg[1]=
\begin{pmatrix}
\arg[2]& \arg[3] \\
\arg[4]& \arg[5]
\end{pmatrix}
}
```

and inside the body to have access not the the list \arg[k] but \A[k] if I call as \MAT{A, 1, 2, 3, 4}.

I tried:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\newcommand{\MAT}[1]{
\setsepchar{,}
\readlist\arh{#1}
\def\arg{\arh[1]}
\readlist\arg{#1} % I want here instead of string "arg" ==>>> the value in \arh[1]
\arg[1]=
\begin{pmatrix}
\arg[2]& \arg[3] \\
\arg[4]& \arg[5]
\end{pmatrix}
}

\begin{document}
$\MAT{A, 1, 2, 3, 4}$
$\A[1]$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ohhh thanks David Carlisle you edited my text. I am new here. By the way how to correctly mention other's member comments  ?    For instance @David ... or what ?

Comment: There is a big risk with such an approach, namely to redefine important commands. If you try `\MAT{H,1,2,3,4}`, and your document cites Erdős, you'd get *very* puzzling error messages.

Comment: Maybe @egreg but for what I am after it is worth the risk. I am right now reading 3 tex books in order to learn the language and make it safer. Among the books the main one I read in the past, it was that written by Knuth.

Comment: your `@` ping worked:-) normally the full user name is prompted if you type the first letter but I'm not sure it does after an edit rather than a comment thread

Comment: you could no doubt implement it but the requested syntax seems a bit odd with the array name being in the same list as the values, wouldn't `\MAT{A}{1, 2, 3, 4}` be more natural?

Comment: @LindomarCarvalho To ping somebody in comments, start by typing `@` and you'll see the possible names, just hit tab when you've chosen the right one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how useful this would be, but you're the judge.

I'd ***not*** use such a short name, because you risk to overwrite important commands.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\MAT}{mm}
 {
  \clist_clear_new:c { l__lindomar_matrix_#1_clist }
  \clist_set:cn { l__lindomar_matrix_#1_clist } { #2 }
  \cs_set_protected:cpn { #1 } { \PRINTMAT { #1 } } %%%% <--- risky
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\PRINTMAT}{mo}
 {
  \IfValueTF { #2 }
   {% just one entry
    \clist_item:cn { l__lindomar_matrix_#1_clist } { #2 }
   }
   {% the whole matrix
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \clist_item:cn { l__lindomar_matrix_#1_clist } { 1 } &
    \clist_item:cn { l__lindomar_matrix_#1_clist } { 2 } \\
    \clist_item:cn { l__lindomar_matrix_#1_clist } { 3 } &
    \clist_item:cn { l__lindomar_matrix_#1_clist } { 4 }
    \end{pmatrix}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\MAT{A}{1,2,3,4}

\begin{document}

\[
A=\A \qquad A_{12}=\A[2]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]